# Deleting rows in excel file using python

Tags: python, excel, file, rows

I have an array with various values in python. Those values belong to a column in an excel file. How can I delete all the rows from excel file containing those values? Can I delete those rows directly by using some function in excel?

Comment: Have you looked into pywin32? http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your question, but may be of interest given your needs.

> "[xlwings](http://xlwings.org) is a BSD-licensed Python library that makes it easy to
>   call Python from Excel and vice versa"

Answer (score 0):

If there are say 25 Excel rows from say 30 to 49 that you are checking values  and the value you are checking is in say column 10 then:

for i in range(25):

if sh.Cells(i+30,10).Value == "whatever value you are checking":

```
   sh.Cells(1+30,10).EntireRow.Delete()
```